# How can I prevent Eric Hynds Multiselect Widget's uncheck all / check all functions without monkeying?

Tags: jquery, widget, multi-select

I'm using the autocomplete and trackpadscroll widgets to show one MultiSelect element and eventhough I am on it using a single text header option and later on appending the links for check all and uncheck all, it's always selecting (unchecking or checking all of the nodes) eventhough they are not visible. Any way to bypass this?

I have tried the following and doesn't seem to work:

//Just some part of the code, specifically one MultiSelect widget from Eric Hynds plugin (**http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/**)

```
       var o1= $('select#select1').multiselect('widget');

       header: "Contacts filtered and available for tag assignment<span style='display:inner-block; float:right; margin-top:0.5em;'> Tag label: <b><?=$tag_label?></span>",


            checkAll:function(event, ui){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    o1.find("label").each(function(){  
                    var labelx = $(this).hasClass('x');

                    if( $(this).find(':checkbox').is(":not(':checked')") && $(labelx).is(':visible') )
                        {
                        $(this).click();
                        }

                 })
```

---

**Edit NOV 20**: I don't think Uncheck all gives any troubles, after all even if it unchecks all (as originally I'm not rendering them.. basically I'm looking into a db and checking if a contact is tagged with a label from a tag tree created with jstree plugin from Ivan Bozhanov) The problem is mainly with the check all hook (It's marking as checked all li elements even if they are not visible on a filtered search... this cause them to update them incorrectly with a later AJAX processing script) as I've monkeyed the code-base but it's shared with another section of this web project. At this stage the client decided to put on hold this feature, but it needs to be enhanced for next versions.. aka it's a well tested bug with the interface. This feature will allow to remove and add contacts to a tag from the tag tree.

Orignally will show at the right hand side an Eric Hynds widget (reworked though to not be a dropdown but simply a  list). At the left hand side, there should be shown nothing but an input text field. When the user types in something there, it calls a jQuery UI autocomplete implementation which requests from the db the contacts that have been found by the user's first, lastname, email, domain email address and combination of some of them via AJAX.

When it comes back it shows up a list of results on the Eric Hynds widget at the left hand side. At the time the user clicks on 'Check All' it should mark only the ones that are visible, as those are the results from a search of contacts to be added to the right hand select. This is done by executing some hooks and bindings on Eric Hynds plugin. so we have two instances of them, therefore the reference to select1.. we are transfering from one to other select dropdown and then reinitializing later when the user hits

[**UPDATE NOV 25**] So this is a real time tag assignment tool that is a core feature requested by a client of mine. Please help! I'm offering some of my own reputation even not having much because I really would like some other developer perspective as to what could work and I can provide more info if necessary ;)

Later on I append these items into an Eric Hynds reworked widget. +(no dropdowns, but there is another section that does use it with them) to that specific header, but it's still checking and unchecking the elements even if they are not visible (I determine this as we type into the autocomplete widget it adds up a class of 'x' to that label, and it updates everything correctly on the front end and on the back-end excerpt for the uncheck all and check all)

Any way to prevent it from happening without monkeying the source code (ok it could be a little bit ) for the multiselect widget?

It's been re-used in another screen and there it works just fine with the checking all and unchecking all that way..

Comment: I'm not really sure what extension you are using. Is it this?
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: hey twiz, thanks for your fast response. Yes, you are correct. I'm using that one exactly. Eric Hynds jQuery UI MultiSelect Plugin with a few other jQuery plugins in this project. I've implemented it and made a few changes.. so it's talking to jQuery UI Autocomplete and jQuery Trackpadscroll Emulator widgets ...Mainly my question is about how to enable multi-select check all to work only of visible elements of the list.. Is for a search type feature, and it should render the options as you type characters on the textbox.

Comment: Could you use http://jsfiddle.net/ to make a simple example that illustrates the problem? I've used the plugin myself, but I am not really sure I understand the issue you are dealing with.

Comment: good suggestion, will work on it in a few. many thx-